# Adding new row to grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I require a `Kendo Grid` for the user to enter 'n' number of results, then click a button (seperate from the grid control) which will take all the results added to the grid and save them to the database. This should be a simple task considering there are no `CRUD` operations going on with the grid itself except to add additional, blank rows for data entry...

HOWEVER,

The problem is that the content of the grid is not static and can vary in column size (from 1 to 6) based on user input (my example shows how this will be represented in the form of an array `Lots`). It seems that most if not all tutorials available seem to focus solely on static content with very little help when it comes to anything else.

So far (with some feedback from Telerik) I have come up with the following...

Set up a Lot Schema i.e. a placeholder for all the data for each `Lot` in the array:

```
var Lots = [];
    Lots.push({ ID: 13, LotNumber: "158UL" }),
    Lots.push({ ID: 14, LotNumber: "646UE" });

var LotResultsSchema = [];
    for (var p = 0; p < Lots.length; ++p) {
        LotResultsSchema.push({
            Result: {
                Count: '', 
                Mean: '',  
                SD: ''     
            }
        });
    }
```

Set up the overall grid Schema Model ID:

```
var schemaModel = kendo.data.Model.define({
        id: "ID",
        fields: {
            ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
            ResultDateTime: {
                type: "date", validation: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            LotResults: LotResultsSchema,           
            StandardComment: {
                ID: {
                    nullable: true, validation: {
                        required: false
                    }
                },
                Description: {
                    defaultValue: "<empty>",
                    validation: {
                        required: false
                    }
                }
            },
            ReviewComment: {
                ID: {
                    nullable: true, validation: {
                        required: false
                    }
                },
                Description: {
                    defaultValue: "<empty>",
                    validation: {
                        required: false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Set up the datasource for the grid based on the schema above:

```
var gridConfigDataSourceAdd = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [],           
        schema: {
            model: schemaModel
        }
    });
```

Set up the column schema (again taking into account that there can be multiple columns created based on array size):

```
var columnSchema = [];
columnSchemaAdd.push({ field: "ResultDateTime", format: "{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss}", editor: dateTimeEditor, title: 'Date Time' });
    for (var j = 0; j < Lots.length; ++j) {
        columnSchemaAdd.push({
            title: Lots[j].LotNumber,
            field: Lots[j].ID,
            columns: [{
                field: "LotResults[" + j + "].Result.Count",
                title: 'Count'
            }, {
                field: "LotResults[" + j + "].Result.Mean",
                title: 'Mean'
            }, {
                field: "LotResults[" + j + "].Result.SD",
                title: 'SD'
            }]
        });
    }
    columnSchemaAdd.push({ field: "StandardComment", title: 'Comment', editor: standardCommentDropDownEditor, template: "#=StandardComment.Description#" });
    columnSchemaAdd.push({ field: "ReviewComment", title: 'Review Comment', editor: reviewCommentDropDownEditor, template: "#=ReviewComment.Description#" });
    columnSchemaAdd.push({ command: ["edit", "destroy"] });
```

Set up the overall grid:

```
$("#configAddGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridConfigDataSourceAdd,
        height: 550,
        navigatable: true,
        autoBind: false,
        editable: {
            mode: "inline"
        },
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: columnSchemaAdd
    });
```

Running this code and clicking the 'Add New' button to create a new row produces the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Result' of undefined

I understand *why* I am getting this error, due to the new item being created with undefined `LotResults`. What I can't understand is how this can happen when the default values are being set up in the Lot Schema.

Any advice is appreciated, I am hoping someone has used Kendo Grids for the same purpose before as I would really like to get a look at an example which works!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with LotResultsSchema. Instead of creating it as a separate array, can try to merge it to the fields class?

```
<script>
var Lots = [];
    Lots.push({ ID: 13, LotNumber: "158UL" }),
    Lots.push({ ID: 14, LotNumber: "646UE" });


  var fields1 =  {
            ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
            ResultDateTime: {
                type: "date", validation: {
                    required: true
                }
            },          
            StandardComment: {
                ID: {
                    nullable: true, validation: {
                        required: false
                    }
                },
                Description: {
                    defaultValue: "<empty>",
                    validation: {
                        required: false
                    }
                }
            },
            ReviewComment: {
                ID: {
                    nullable: true, validation: {
                        required: false
                    }
                },
                Description: {
                    defaultValue: "<empty>",
                    validation: {
                        required: false
                    }
                }
            }
  };
    for (var p = 0; p < Lots.length; ++p) {
            fields1['Count' + Lots[p].ID] = {type : "number"};
            fields1['Mean'+Lots[p].ID] = {type : "number"};
            fields1['SD' +Lots[p].ID] = {type : "number"};        
    }
  var schemaModel = kendo.data.Model.define({
        id: "ID",
        fields: fields1
    });

  var gridConfigDataSourceAdd = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [],           
        schema: {
            model: schemaModel
        }
    });

  var columnSchemaAdd = [];
columnSchemaAdd.push({ field: "ResultDateTime", format: "{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss}",  title: 'Date Time' });
    for (var j = 0; j < Lots.length; ++j) {
        columnSchemaAdd.push({
            title: Lots[j].LotNumber,
            field: Lots[j].ID,
            columns: [{
                field: 'Count' + Lots[j].ID ,
                title: 'Count'
            }, 
            {
                field: 'Mean'+Lots[j].ID ,
                title: 'Mean'
            }, {
                field: 'SD' + Lots[j].ID ,
               title: 'SD'
            }]
        });
    }
    columnSchemaAdd.push({ field: "StandardComment", title: 'Comment',  template: "#=StandardComment.Description#" });
    columnSchemaAdd.push({ field: "ReviewComment", title: 'Review Comment',  template: "#=ReviewComment.Description#" });
    columnSchemaAdd.push({ command: ["edit", "destroy"] });
  $("#configAddGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridConfigDataSourceAdd,
        height: 550,
        navigatable: true,
        autoBind: false,
        editable: {
            mode: "inline"
        },
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: columnSchemaAdd
    });

  </script>
```

A sample http://dojo.telerik.com/uHucA

Comment: thanks for the reply. I had looked into this approach (which does work as expected) however the attributes are saved in such a way which would require more work when saving out to the DB. I.e. I want the Count, Mean and SD fields to be grouped together and with their associated LotID/Number. Do you have any idea how this could be achieved?

Comment: from my personal experience I haven't seen fields binding to complex types. It usually supports types like number,string, date etc.